# Trouble with integer partition proof

Tags: combinatorics, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I am reading Keller & Trotter: Applied Combinatorics, pg. 155, and I am having trouble with an intermediate step in a proof.

The proof deals with integer partitions:

[image]

And the part I can't figure out is when the the author says:$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^n) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n-1})\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2n})$$ ...at line two of the math content, next to the second equals sign aligned to the left:

[image]

How does he get there?

Comment: Is it clearer written in the following way:  $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^n) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2k-1})\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1 - x^{2k})$, setting $n=2k$ or $n=2k+1$ according to the parity of $n$ ?

Comment: It's just splitting the left product into the cases where $n$ is odd and where $n$ is even. It's a bit confusing since the right products both use $n$. Easier to see as $$(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)\cdots = \left((1-x^2)(1-x^4)(1-x^6)\dots\right)\left((1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\cdots\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They’re simply splitting the product into factors with an odd exponent and factors with an even exponent:

$$\prod_{n\ge 1}\left(1-x^n\right)=\prod_{n\ge 1}\left(\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)\left(1-x^{2n}\right)\right)=\prod_{n\ge 1}\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)\prod_{n\ge 1}\left(1-x^{2n}\right)\;.$$

When $n=1$, for instance, $$\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)\left(1-x^{2n}\right)=(1-x)\left(1-x^2\right)\;,$$ and when $n=2$, $$\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)\left(1-x^{2n}\right)=\left(1-x^3\right)\left(1-x^4\right)\;.$$

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks, I get it now.  In the $(1-x^n)$ case, if $n=1$, it yields $(1-x)$.  How is it that the statements can be equivalent if they cant equal eachother at specific $n$'s?  (Does it have to do with the behavior of infinite products, emphasis on the infinite part?)

Comment: @bordeo: All that matters is that you’re multiplying together the same factors in both expressions; how you name them is irrelevant. For instance, $\prod_{n=1}^5n=\prod_{n=6}^{10}(n-5)$, even though the two products don’t even *have* a value of $n$ in common.

Comment: Got it.  I was thinking that, if the terms were generated iteratively, then at any given $n$, the $\prod (1-x^n)$ would have generated one term at each $n$, and the multiplicative form would have generated two terms...so that $\prod_{n=1}^{2}(1-x^{2n-1})\prod_{n=1}^{2}(1-x^{2n}) = \prod_{n=1}^{4} (1-x^n)$...but $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(...)\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(...) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-x^{2n})$, because of how infinity works? (just an aside at this point...thank you for the answer)

Comment: @bordeo: If these were finite products, we could pull a similar stunt, but the upper limits would change. For instance, $$\prod_{n=1}^{100}\left(1-x^n\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{50}\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right) \prod_{n=1}^{50}\left(1-x^{2n}\right)\;.$$ You’re welcome.